# What's the best practices in C# for public members that must be used for internal use only?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

In a scenario similar to the one described [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/441768/how-do-i-design-a-drawing-program-with-the-separation-of-concerns), I have 2 different assemblies and I need to declare some members in classes of assembly A that must be used only by my classes in assembly B (I mean, who uses a class of the assembly A must be discouraged to call/use those methods/properties/fields).

What is the best practice to declare them?

1. Creating an interface for them (so you need to explicitly cast the class of assembly A to the interface to see them)
2. Naming them with a particular prefix (so I can "train my user" to avoid calling/using them)
3. Naming them with the first letter lowercase (so Intellisense will put them at the end and they will be "more hidden")

Notes:

- Assembly A is built against .net6 (cross-platform) and assembly B is built against net6-windows (O.S. Windows specific)
- I can't use [InternalsVisibleTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) because Assembly A must be obfuscated and this prevents obfuscation for internal members.

Listed below is the code for a better explanation of those cases.

---

### assembly A

case 1

```
public class Workspace : IWorkspaceInternal
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Does stuff.
   /// </summary>
   public void MyRealPublicMethod() { //do something }

   /// <summary>
   /// For internal use only.
   /// </summary>
   void IWorkspaceInternal.MyMethod1() { //do something }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interfaces with methods/properties/classes for internal use only.
/// </summary>
public interface IWorkspaceInternal
{       
   /// <summary>
   /// Does stuff.
   /// </summary>
   public void MyMethod1() { //do something }
}
```

case 2

```
public class Workspace
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Does stuff.
   /// </summary>
   public void MyRealPublicMethod() { //do something }

   /// <summary>
   /// For internal use only.
   /// </summary>
   public void Foo_Method1() { //do something }
}
```

case 3

```
public class Workspace
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Does stuff.
   /// </summary>
   public void MyRealPublicMethod() { //do something }

   /// <summary>
   /// For internal use only.
   /// </summary>
   public void myInternalMethod1() { //do something }
}
```

Other ideas?

Comment: If you can't make your type internal, nothing will prevent others from calling it. _HOW_ you go about discouraging them is really up to you but they are all fundamentally poor options since nothing prohibits the caller. In a perfect world, you would make the type internal and expose a factory creation pattern that resolves to an interface.

Comment: "Embelish" the interface with reflection. Make it so that interface is usable only with a bit of reflection shenanigans.

Comment: @DavidL Yes, that's why I asked for the best practise... maybe I can fix the title

Comment: @ilCosmico I don't see a way around your second bullet point however. If you cannot make the class internal, I don't see a way forward for you. Perhaps you could ship the functionality in a separate assembly.

Comment: What about making `IWorkspaceInternal`  internal and moving it into the 3rd assembly which would not be obfuscated (and using `InternalsVisibleTo`)? Another option - marking the method with `Obsolete` attribute (will not prevent the usage but will discourage it).

Comment: @GuruStron `IWorkspaceInternal` can declare members of a type declared in assembly A, so moving it into a 3rd assembly (let's say assembly C) will create a circular reference among assemblies A and C. Moreover, I don't like to have a 3rd assembly to deploy for a single interface :)

Comment: That depends on what the actual worst-case scenario is if a consumer of Assembly B calls a method on a class in Assembly A.

Comment: @ilCosmico since you want to achieve an impossible (at least by definition) - hide a public member you should consider some trade offs =) _"IWorkspaceInternal can declare members of a type declared in assembly A"_ - that is an information which was not present in the question =)

Comment: Also another potential approach - conditional compilation.

Comment: I would also go by solving this issue by documentation. And documentation might mean putting a "dontUse" into the method or interface name so be it then. In the end you can try to prevent misuse but there still will be someone thinking reflection is just a normal tool to use to get what he wants.

Comment: Does your obfuscator allow merging (often a feature of those tools)? That might help crossing the "internals" boundary.

Comment: @Ralf they must be 2 separated assemblies: one net6 and the other one net6-windows.

Comment: @ilCosmico i would expect that to work on the windows platform but yeah using the crossplatform assembly on other platforms and a merged one on windows might lead to some lets say interesting referencing problems in the build process.

Comment: If you have members of a class in assembly a that should only be used in assembly b then it sounds like what you want to do is extend the class in assembly b and add them there, or extend the interface and add them there.

Comment: @ZachHutchins fact is that classes in assembly B have a different hierarchy, so they cannot derive from classes in assembly A. Moreover, assembly B reference A and not vice versa.

Comment: Maybe you want that B (windows only) class can be used only by classes within the same platform?

Comment: @kiggyttass I can't understand the sense of the question, sorry. No matter about how are used classes in assembly B.